# Angular - which bootstrap is best for developing a angular cli application

Tags: angular, angular-cli, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I am new to angular world. I want to know which bootstrap should i use for developing my angular application. [ng bootstrap link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home)  or [bootstrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/getting-started/introduction/)
I am keen to learn typescript and i have worked on bootstrap 4 link which is mentioned above.

If i choose exisiting bootstrap 4 how can i convert the js call to typescript call for eg opening modal in js will written like this :

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myInput').focus()
})
```

How should i write this js call in my component file. Please suggest the right approach to work with angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not directly manipulate the DOM in angular. So use ng-bootstrap.

More, the API is more elegant in ng-bootstrap because it uses the power of components and directives. For example, it's cleaner to write that:

```
<ngb-progressbar type="info" [value]="50"></ngb-progressbar>
```

than that:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: yeah if i m in angular world thats one single line is better to write i guess

Comment: It will make your life easier :-). If bootstrap is not mandatory for you, you might want to take a look to the material lib. It's pretty and powerful. https://material.angular.io/components/categories.

Comment: only issue which i am facing is for e.g i need a customised drop down with search option and once user search something in drop down i need to fetch the result from backend based on his search. if i use ng boostrap will i be stuck in this scenario

Comment: No, it's not related to ng-boostrap but to Angular. I'm not familiar with ng-boostrap but i guess you can add an input to the drop down. Then you just have to bind this input to angular using reactive forms or template-driven forms. Take a look to the doc: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms